# How can we configure an existing cluster to run with Databricks notebook being triggered using REST API calls through shell script?

Tags: azure, rest, shell, databricks

We are trying to trigger an existing Azure Databricks Notebook using a REST API Call through the shell script. There are existing clusters running in the workspace. We want to attach the Databricks notebook with an existing cluster and trigger the Notebook

We are trying to figure out the configuration and the REST API Call that can trigger the notebook with a specific cluster dynamically at the run time.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got the below results.

Here, I have created two clusters **C1** and **C2** and two notebooks `Nb1` and `Nb2`.

**My **Nb1** notebook code for sample:**

`print("Hello world")`

I have created **Nb1 job** and executed with **C1** cluster by using the below shell script from **Nb2** which is attached with **C2**.

```
%sh
curl -n --header "Authorization: Bearer <Access token>" \
-X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
     "run_name": "My Notebook run",
     "existing_cluster_id": "<cluster id>",
     "notebook_task": 
     {
      "notebook_path": "<Your Notebook path>"
      }
    }' https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/jobs/runs/submit
```

**Execution from `Nb2:`**

[image]

**Job Created:**

[image]

**Job Output:**

[image]